# SD Card is not a directory any more in Eclipse

Tags: android

I have updated my ADT to rev 20 yesterday and after that I have come across this strange problem where my sdcard was not a directory but rather it was a file in the Eclipse File Explorer.

My emulator corresponding to that was created even before I updated the ADT.

Can anyone explain me , what could be wrong?

NOTE : This is a problem corrsponding to only one of my emulator (SDK Version 10)

Comment: do you have your sd card mounted as external storage?

Comment: What about `/mnt/sdcard`

Comment: I've the directory in `mnt/sdcard/` check it in yours

Comment: @Andro Selva, have you got the sdcard directory under mnt directory?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find the content of the `sdcard` folder in the `mnt/sdcard` folder.

Answer (score 1):

The File Explorer plugin in eclipse won't follow symbolic links. Instead it displays most directories like the following as empty directories:

- /sdcard
- /mnt/sdcard
- /mnt/sdcard/external (external micro SD of a Galaxy Tab GT-P1000)
- /storage/sdcard0
- /storage/emulated/legacy

On my Galaxy Nexus the physical path (mount point) to the builtin flash memory / sdcard is:

- /storage/shell/0

So the solution might be to navigate all paths - seem they likely or not - to find out where the manufacturer of the device decided to hide the mount point.

Answer (score 0):

Explore **mnt>sdcard** (mnt which is 6th directory in your image) instead of sbin and see it.

Comment: Sorry to say, but the `sdcard` is **NOT** in the `sbin` folder on this image.

Comment: @bicska88, Just find 9th directory in the given image which is sbin, which contains sdcard but it is not directory. The same is asked by Andro Selva.

Comment: And don't say Sorry to any-one, just make the right argument, that is all.

Comment: And yup, any-one can make mistake, just refresh your browser screen before posting answer, so that you can find the latest answers, and Duplicate Answers and not be posted.

Comment: I know where it is, thanks. But you said that `Explore mnt>sdcard (mnt which is 6th directory in your image) instead of sbin and see it.` My understanding is that you think that Andro Selva found the `sdcard` **IN** the `sbin` folder. But at this point you are **WRONG**, since it is on the same level in the file hierarchy, where the `sbin` directory is. Btw, I understood your answer for the first time. You did get me wrong.

Comment: Mine is not your answer's duplicate, sir, see above the explanation why.

Comment: Yup, I accept that was mistake of understanding the levels and I got you properly. But Sir, the Answer given by me is oldest; if you want to check, just press **Oldest** button which is given at right end.